# intellij: update classes in classpath for python plug-in

Tags: python, intellij-idea

community!

My problem:
I have an item, namely `gi.repository.Gtk`, marked as "Unresolved reference: Gtk".

The Gtk module did not exist at the moment of setting up Python SDK in Idea, however I've installed it little bit later.

I can't get how do I force re-sync of classpath for python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the binary modules for a Python interpreter are rescanned on IntelliJ IDEA restart. Please try restarting the IDE.

Comment: Hmmm. No other way available? This is OK, But not comfortable. I've restarted IDE and it seems to work for me.

Comment: PyCharm has some specific UI to reload the binary modules without restarting the IDE, but it's not available in the Python plugin, because it uses the standard IntelliJ IDEA SDK configuration UI. As far as I know restart is the only option.